# Table cell with an Image and Text centered underneath

Tags: css, html

I am a student and am trying to create a table with a image centered within a cell. I also want to add text underneath the image centered within the same cell. Here is my html and css so far. Attached an image.

```
table { margin: auto;
        width: 70%;
        height: 500px;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 20px;
}
.tableImage { background-image: url(chick.png);
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-position: center
}
caption { font-size: 1.5em;
}      
td, th { border: 2px solid #3399cc;
         padding: 5px;
}
td { text-align: center;
}
tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #b3cce6;
}
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: #b3e6cc;
}


<table>
<caption>The Polish Chicken</caption>
<tr>
  <th>text</th>
  <th>text</ht>
  <th>text</th>
<th>text</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>text</td>
  <td colspan="2", rowspan="4", td class="tableImage">Silver Laced Polish Chicken</td>
  <td>text</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What does  <td colspan="2", rowspan="4", td class="tableImage"> mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/pwa6kg62/1/

```
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="4" valign="bottom" class="tableImage">
```

I have used valign property of a table cell to align the text vertically.

I am sure you have your reasons, but it is highly recommended that one does not use table cells for layout. If you have any questions, please leave a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Give the .tableImage class a padding-top that is larger than your image.

For example:

```
.tableImage{ padding-top:200px;}
```

Here is a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/0xjygxmt/1/

Minor side notes, I see are that you have the "t" and "h" transposed in your second closing `</th>` tag and no closing `<table>` tag, but those wouldn't affect the cell in question.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response., I corrected typo and used the valign="bottom".